# Changing File Module's {file_size} variable into MB

Tags: files

Is there an easy way to change the File Module's {file_size} variable from its default output of bytes, into megabytes?

Seems just slack not to provide a better user friendly output that what's on offer out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use any mathematics plugin which to calculate megabytes from bytes. You can use [Simple Math](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/simple-math) plugin and use tag like

```
{exp:simple_math calculate="{file_size} / 1024"}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a start. Shame there's no built in 'friendly' flag that outputs KB size up to 1MB, then MB up to 1GB etc.

Comment: Thanks! I am also very surprised we need a plugin to do this.